# StackOverflowException Function in unity gameobject.transform.childcount

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Unity Error Show

StackOverflowException
CheckWord.GettingLength (UnityEngine.GameObject obj) (at Assets/Scripts/Player/CheckWord.cs:906)

Function is getting inner child count of a game object:-

```
   using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class CheckWord : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject DropZone;
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject KiloMeter;
    public GameObject OKiloMeter;
    public GameObject WinStatus;
    public GameObject TournamentWin;
    public GameObject KeyBoardLock;

    public Transform camera_main;

    [Header("CameraRelated")]
    public float power =1.7f;
    public float duration=0.5f;
    public float slowDownAmount=0.5f;
    public bool shouldShake = false;





    Vector3 startposition;
    float initalDuration;


    public TextAsset WordList;

    [HideInInspector]
    public string[] txtlist;

    GameObject[] AllChild;
    string MakeWord="";
    int WordValue;

    Animator anim;
    Rigidbody2D body;



    string LevelName="";

    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueA = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueB = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueC = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueD = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueE = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueF = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueG = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueH = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueI = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueJ = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueK = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueL = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueM = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueN = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueO = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueP = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueQ = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueR = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueS = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueT = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueU = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueV = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueW = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueX = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueY = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int ValueZ = 0;



    [Header("KeyBoard")]
    public GameObject Letter_A;
    public GameObject Letter_B;
    public GameObject Letter_C;
    public GameObject Letter_D;
    public GameObject Letter_E;
    public GameObject Letter_F;
    public GameObject Letter_G;
    public GameObject Letter_H;
    public GameObject Letter_I;
    public GameObject Letter_J;
    public GameObject Letter_K;
    public GameObject Letter_L;
    public GameObject Letter_M;
    public GameObject Letter_N;
    public GameObject Letter_O;
    public GameObject Letter_P;
    public GameObject Letter_Q;
    public GameObject Letter_R;
    public GameObject Letter_S;
    public GameObject Letter_T;
    public GameObject Letter_U;
    public GameObject Letter_V;
    public GameObject Letter_W;
    public GameObject Letter_X;
    public GameObject Letter_Y;
    public GameObject Letter_Z;


    [Header("Panel")]
    public GameObject UpperPanel;
    public GameObject MiddlePanel;
    public GameObject Middle1Panel;
    public GameObject BottomPanel;


    string KiloM="";
    int TournamentScene;
    int objCount;






    public void Start()
    {
        LevelName = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("buttonName","Sprint");
        GenrateWord ();
        KiloMeter.GetComponent<Text> ().text ="120";
        OKiloMeter.GetComponent<Text> ().text ="120";
        KiloM=KiloMeter.GetComponent<Text> ().text ;
        TournamentScene = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Tournament", 0);
        InitWord ();
        WordValue = 0;
        camera_main = Camera.main.transform;
        startposition = camera_main.localPosition;
        initalDuration = duration;

        StartCoroutine (wordraw());
    }

    IEnumerator wordraw()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            CreateWords ();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.001f);
        }
        System.GC.Collect ();
    }

    public void InitWord()
    {
        switch (LevelName) 
        {
        case "SPRINT":

            ValueA = 1;
            Letter_A.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_A");

            ValueB= 3;
            Letter_B.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite>("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_B");

            ValueC = 3;
            Letter_C.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite>("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_C");

            ValueD = 2;
            Letter_D.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite>("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_D");

            ValueE = 1;
            Letter_E.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_E");

            ValueF = 4;
            Letter_F.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite>("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_F");

            ValueG = 2;
            Letter_G.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_G");

            ValueH = 4;
            Letter_H.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_H");

            ValueI = 1;
            Letter_I.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_I");

            ValueJ = 8;
            Letter_J.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_J");

            ValueK = 5;
            Letter_K.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_K");

            ValueL = 1;
            Letter_L.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_L");

            ValueM = 3;
            Letter_M.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_M");

            ValueN = 1;
            Letter_N.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_N");

            ValueO = 1;
            Letter_O.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_O");

            ValueP = 3;
            Letter_P.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_P");

            ValueQ = 10;
            Letter_Q.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_Q");

            ValueR = 1;
            Letter_R.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_R");

            ValueS = 1;
            Letter_S.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite>("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_S");

            ValueT = 1;
            Letter_T.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_T");

            ValueU = 1;
            Letter_U.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_U");

            ValueV = 4;
            Letter_V.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_v");

            ValueW = 4;
            Letter_W.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_W");

            ValueX = 8;
            Letter_X.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_X");

            ValueY = 4;
            Letter_Y.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite>("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_Y");

            ValueZ = 10;
            Letter_Z.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_Z");

            break;

        case "TIME":

            ValueA = 1;
            Letter_A.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_A");

            ValueB= 1;
            Letter_B.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_B");

            ValueC = 1;
            Letter_C.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_C");

            ValueD = 1;
            Letter_D.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_D");

            ValueE = 1;
            Letter_E.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_E");

            ValueF = 1;
            Letter_F.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_F");

            ValueG = 1;
            Letter_G.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_G");

            ValueH = 1;
            Letter_H.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_H");

            ValueI = 1;
            Letter_I.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_I");

            ValueJ = 1;
            Letter_J.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_J");

            ValueK = 1;
            Letter_K.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_K");

            ValueL = 1;
            Letter_L.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_L");

            ValueM = 1;
            Letter_M.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_M");

            ValueN = 1;
            Letter_N.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_N");

            ValueO = 1;
            Letter_O.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_O");

            ValueP = 1;
            Letter_P.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_P");

            ValueQ = 1;
            Letter_Q.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_Q");

            ValueR = 1;
            Letter_R.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_R");
            ValueS = 1;

            Letter_S.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_S");

            ValueT = 1;
            Letter_T.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_T");

            ValueU = 1;
            Letter_U.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_U");

            ValueV = 1;
            Letter_V.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_V");

            ValueW = 1;
            Letter_W.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_W");

            ValueX = 1;
            Letter_X.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_X");

            ValueY = 1;
            Letter_Y.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_Y");

            ValueZ = 1;
            Letter_Z.GetComponent<Image>().sprite=Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Time Mode/Eng_Z");

            break;

        case "BLACKOUT":

            ValueA = 1;
            Letter_A.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_A");

            ValueB = 3;
            Letter_B.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_B");

            ValueC = 3;
            Letter_C.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_C");

            ValueD = 2;
            Letter_D.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_D");

            ValueE = 1;
            Letter_E.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_E");

            ValueF = 4;
            Letter_F.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_F");

            ValueG = 2;
            Letter_G.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_G");

            ValueH = 4;
            Letter_H.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_H");

            ValueI = 1;
            Letter_I.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_I");

            ValueJ = 8;
            Letter_J.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_J");

            ValueK = 5;
            Letter_K.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_K");

            ValueL = 1;
            Letter_L.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_L");

            ValueM = 3;
            Letter_M.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_M");

            ValueN = 1;
            Letter_N.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_N");

            ValueO = 1;
            Letter_O.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_O");

            ValueP = 3;
            Letter_P.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_P");

            ValueQ = 10;
            Letter_Q.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_Q");

            ValueR = 1;
            Letter_R.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_R");

            ValueS = 1;
            Letter_S.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_S");

            ValueT = 1;
            Letter_T.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_T");

            ValueU = 1;
            Letter_U.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_U");

            ValueV = 4;
            Letter_V.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_v");

            ValueW = 4;
            Letter_W.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_W");

            ValueX = 8;
            Letter_X.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_X");

            ValueY = 4;
            Letter_Y.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_Y");

            ValueZ = 10;
            Letter_Z.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Images/MainGame/Letters With Values/Sprint Mode/Eng_Z");

            break;
        }

    }


    public void GenrateWord()
    {
        WordList = (TextAsset)Resources.Load ("word list/final_list");
    }



    public void CheckSpell()
    {
        MakeWord = "";

        int tlChild=GettingLength(DropZone); 


        WordValue = 0;
        Debug.Log ("Total Child Lenght" + tlChild.ToString());

        anim=player.GetComponent<Animator> ();
        body=player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        AllChild=new GameObject[tlChild];

        for (int i = 0; i < tlChild; i++) {
            AllChild[i]=DropZone.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
            string ObjectName=DropZone.transform.GetChild (i).gameObject.name.ToString ();
            MakeWord = MakeWord + DropZone.transform.GetChild (i).gameObject.name;
            WordValue = WordValue + ValuesOfWord (ObjectName);
        }

        int z=AllChild.Length;

        Debug.Log ("All Child Lenght" + z.ToString());
        Debug.Log ("MakeWord="+MakeWord);
        if(z>=2){
            if (WordCheck ()) {
                anim.SetInteger ("State", 1);
                Debug.Log ("WordCheck Enter Word is" + MakeWord);
                Debug.Log ("WordCheck Enter WordValue is" + WordValue.ToString ());
                int dis = int.Parse (KiloM);

                for (int i = 0; i < tlChild; i++) {
                    CreateWords ();
                    Destroy (DropZone.transform.GetChild (i).gameObject);

                }



                if (dis >= 0) {
                    dis = dis - WordValue;  
                    if (dis >= 0) {
                        KiloM = dis.ToString ();
                        KiloMeter.GetComponent<Text> ().text = KiloM;
                    } else {
                        if (TournamentScene == 1) {
                            TournamentWin.SetActive (true);
                        } else {
                            WinStatus.SetActive (true);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (TournamentScene == 1) {
                        TournamentWin.SetActive (true);
                    } else {
                        WinStatus.SetActive (true);
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i <= 1 * WordValue; i++) {
                    StartCoroutine (Runner (10 * WordValue));
                }
            } else {
                shouldShake = true;
            }
        } else {
            shouldShake = true;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (shouldShake) {
            if (duration > 0) {
                camera_main.localPosition = camera_main.position + UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitSphere * power;
                duration -= Time.deltaTime * slowDownAmount;
            } else {
                shouldShake = false;
                duration = initalDuration;
                camera_main.localPosition = startposition;
            }
        }
    }


    public bool WordCheck ()
    {
        bool flag = false;

        if (WordList.text.Contains (MakeWord)) {
            flag=true;
        } else {
            flag = false;
        }
        Debug.Log ("Flag="+flag);
        return flag;
    }

    public int ValuesOfWord(string word)
    {
        int SendValue = 0;
        switch (word)
        {
        case "A":
            SendValue = ValueA;
            break;

        case "B":
            SendValue = ValueB;
            break;

        case "C":
            SendValue = ValueC;
            break;

        case "D":
            SendValue = ValueD;
            break;

        case "E":
            SendValue = ValueE;
            break;

        case "F":
            SendValue = ValueF;
            break;

        case "G":
            SendValue = ValueG;
            break;

        case "H":
            SendValue = ValueH;
            break;

        case "I":
            SendValue = ValueI;
            break;

        case "J":
            SendValue = ValueJ;
            break;

        case "K":
            SendValue = ValueK;
            break;

        case "L":
            SendValue = ValueL;
            break;

        case "M":
            SendValue =ValueM;
            break;

        case "N":
            SendValue =ValueN;
            break;

        case "O":
            SendValue =ValueO;
            break;

        case "P":
            SendValue =ValueP;
            break;

        case "Q":
            SendValue =ValueQ;
            break;

        case "R":
            SendValue =ValueR;
            break;

        case "S":
            SendValue = ValueS;
            break;

        case "T":
            SendValue = ValueT;
            break;

        case "U":
            SendValue =ValueU;
            break;

        case "V":
            SendValue =ValueV;
            break;

        case "W":
            SendValue =ValueW;
            break;

        case "X":
            SendValue =ValueX;
            break;

        case "Y":
            SendValue =ValueY;
            break;

        case "Z":
            SendValue = ValueZ;
            break;

        }
        Debug.Log ("SendValue = "+SendValue);
        return SendValue;
    }




    IEnumerator Runner(int n)
    {

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            anim.SetInteger ("State", 1);
            body.AddForce(new Vector2(500f,0));
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.05f);
        }
        anim.SetInteger ("State", 0);
    }

    public void CreateWords()
    {

        int j = randomValueGenrate(0, 25);
        int n = randomValueGenrate(0, 4);
        switch (n) {

        case 0:
            objCount = 0;
            objCount = GettingLength (UpperPanel);

            if (objCount <= 6) {
                GameObject obj=Instantiate (WordsGet (j), UpperPanel.transform) as GameObject;
                obj.name=obj.name.Replace("(Clone)", "");

                if (moreSameObject (obj)) {
                    Destroy (obj);
                    CreateWords ();
                }

            } else {
                CreateWords ();
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            objCount = 0;
            objCount = GettingLength (Middle1Panel);
            if (objCount <= 6) {
                GameObject obj=Instantiate (WordsGet (j), Middle1Panel.transform) as GameObject;
                obj.name=obj.name.Replace("(Clone)", "");

                if (moreSameObject (obj)) {
                    Destroy (obj);
                    CreateWords ();
                }

            } else {
                CreateWords ();
            }

            break;
        case 2:
            objCount=0;
            objCount = GettingLength (MiddlePanel);

            if (objCount <= 6) {
                GameObject obj=Instantiate (WordsGet (j), MiddlePanel.transform) as GameObject;
                obj.name=obj.name.Replace("(Clone)", "");

                if (moreSameObject (obj)) {
                    Destroy (obj);
                    CreateWords ();
                }

            } else {
                CreateWords ();
            }

            break;

        case 3:
            objCount=0;
            objCount = GettingLength (BottomPanel);

            if (objCount <= 6) {
                GameObject obj=Instantiate (WordsGet (j), BottomPanel.transform) as GameObject;
                obj.name=obj.name.Replace("(Clone)", "");

                if (moreSameObject (obj)) {
                    Destroy (obj);
                    CreateWords ();
                }

            } else {
                CreateWords ();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public bool moreSameObject(GameObject LObject)
    {
        int count = 0;
        bool flag = false;

        int UpperSize=0;
        int MiddleSize=0;
        int Middle1Size=0;
        int BottomSize=0;

        UpperSize = GettingLength (UpperPanel);
        MiddleSize = GettingLength (MiddlePanel);
        Middle1Size = GettingLength (Middle1Panel);
        BottomSize = GettingLength (BottomPanel);


        for (int i = 0; i < UpperSize; i++) {
            if (UpperPanel.transform.GetChild (i).name.Equals (LObject.name)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < MiddleSize; i++) {
            if (MiddlePanel.transform.GetChild (i).name.Equals (LObject.name)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Middle1Size; i++) {
            if (Middle1Panel.transform.GetChild (i).name.Equals (LObject.name)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < BottomSize; i++) {
            if (BottomPanel.transform.GetChild (i).name.Equals (LObject.name)) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count > 2) {
            Debug.Log ("Found More then 2"+LObject.name);
            flag = true;
        }

        return flag;
    }

    public GameObject WordsGet(int j)
    {
        GameObject LetterObject=null;

        switch(j)
        {
        case 0:
            LetterObject = Letter_A;
            break;
        case 1:
            LetterObject = Letter_B;
            break;
        case 2:
            LetterObject = Letter_C;
            break;
        case 3:
            LetterObject = Letter_D;
            break;
        case 4:
            LetterObject = Letter_E;
            break;
        case 5:
            LetterObject = Letter_F;
            break;
        case 6:
            LetterObject = Letter_G;
            break;
        case 7:
            LetterObject = Letter_H;
            break;
        case 8:
            LetterObject = Letter_I;
            break;
        case 9:
            LetterObject = Letter_J;
            break;
        case 10:
            LetterObject = Letter_K;
            break;
        case 11:
            LetterObject = Letter_L;
            break;

        case 12:
            LetterObject = Letter_M;
            break;
        case 13:
            LetterObject = Letter_N;
            break;
        case 14:
            LetterObject = Letter_O;
            break;
        case 15:
            LetterObject = Letter_P;
            break;
        case 16:
            LetterObject = Letter_Q;
            break;
        case 17:
            LetterObject = Letter_R;
            break;
        case 18:
            LetterObject = Letter_S;
            break;
        case 19:
            LetterObject = Letter_T;
            break;
        case 20:
            LetterObject = Letter_U;
            break;
        case 21:
            LetterObject = Letter_V;
            break;
        case 22:
            LetterObject = Letter_W;
            break;
        case 23:
            LetterObject = Letter_X;
            break;
        case 24:
            LetterObject = Letter_Y;
            break;
        case 25:
            LetterObject = Letter_Z;
            break;
        }
        Debug.Log ("Letter Name"+LetterObject.name.ToString());
        return LetterObject;
    }


    public int randomValueGenrate(int min,int max)
    {
        System.Random random = new System.Random ();

        int r = random.Next (max-min)+min;

        if (r > max) {
            randomValueGenrate (min, max);
        } else {            
            return r;
        }

        return r;
    }


    public int GettingLength(GameObject obj)
    {
        if (null == obj)
        {
            return 0;
            Debug.Log ("Getting Object is Null");
        }

        int count = 0;

        foreach (Transform child in obj.transform)
        {
            if (null != child) {
                count += 1;

            } else {
                continue;
                Debug.Log ("Getting Chils is N");
            }

        }

        return count;
    }

}
```

Error Show this line (foreach (Transform child in obj.transform))

before this function, i use Gameobject.transform.childcount it also show same the error

I can't find the right answer in anywhere
if anybody knows how to resolve it then give me answer

[image]

Comment: I don't think the code in this question is causing this error. If possible, post your complete `CheckWord` script.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q9n-ispliUd9Y9wyrg_a3YZghj2yUbKv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please check this file given above"

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q9n-ispliUd9Y9wyrg_a3YZghj2yUbKv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Edit and post `CheckWord` in your question.

Comment: please check it updated

Comment: When people ask you to update your question, please do so without removing your old code. Simply add EDIT followed by your new code because your edit made my first comment look irrelevant. The problem is in your `randomValueGenrate` function. What is that function supposed to do? If you can explain it maybe there is a better way to do that.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion .In future, I remember this tips 

'RandomValueGenrate' Function is using for generating random value because unity was cause on random function and stop the unity also close the game 

if the random value is bigger then max value it again generating the value

Comment: I still don't understand what that function is supposed to do...Generate random number between min and max? If so, what is the `if (r > max) {` used for? You know you can simply use `UnityEngine.Random.Range(min, max);` to generate random number in Unity.

Comment: before this function, I use **UnityEngine.Random.Range(min, max); ** but it also crashes with same error soi think I create own random function with c#

I also Think function that it return large number so I create this function.

Comment: You have to remove the `randomValueGenrate (min, max);` inside the `if (r > max) {` statement. that's what is causing that crash.

Comment: it shows again the error after removing this function it shows error faster otherwise it shows error but later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `Destroy()` with `DestroyImmediate()` in your script.

Here is a detailed explanation:
If you use the `Destroy()` function to destroy a `GameObject`, Unity doesn't destroy it right away. What it actually does is just mark it as `null` and destroy it in later frames. So if you destroy a `GameObject` in one frame, and query for the child count in exact the same frame, the number you get will not be decremented. If you do it with `DestroyImmediate()`, the `GameObject`, as it is marked in the function signature, will be immediately destroyed, and the child count will be decremented instantaneously.
In your case, the `CreateWords()` function destroys the created letter object if there is already another letter same as the one you've created, and then call the function itself again. However, even if the letter object is destroyed, the child count still increases by 1. At last, the function will find that every panel has more than 6 letters (while actually there aren't), causing an infinite recursive loop which crash the program.

Comment: you got all most but I concept is if panel size is less than 6  then transform the Letter_object otherwise Destroy Created Object and Call The CreateWords();

Thank You answer is more suitable for me

If I Destroy The Object then How panel Childcount is increased by 1
Please, Can you explain?

Comment: What I mean is that Destroy() doesn't decrease the child count immediately in the frame you call it. So as you have created a letter object and you destroy it, the child count in this frame will be increased by 1.